# Mobile broadband connects to 3G after selecting 2G in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless, usb-modem, 3g

I am using a `Huawei e303c` HSDPA modem to connect to a wireless network on **Ubuntu 14.04LTS.** The modem configuration was done using the Connection manager and the HSDPA network works flawlessly. However, when I force the modem to connect to a 2G (EDGE) network, the modem still connects to 3G (HSDPA).

Moreover, the connection mode **latches** from Windows. It means that if I use 2G on Windows (Windows 7, in a dual boot), the modem connects with the 2G network on Ubuntu, regardless of the Connection Type selected in the connection manager.

Is there any way to force the modem to connect to the specified network mode? Is this a known bug? How can I resolve this issue?

EDIT: Output of `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` :

> /dev/ttyUSB0    /dev/ttyUSB1    /dev/ttyUSB2

The modem is `/dev/tty/USB2`.

Comment: @Fabby By selecting the network type in the connection configuration.

Comment: @Fabby Output of `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` in the edited question. I have no issues in the detection of the device.

Comment: Wonderful!  Try the following command using [minicom](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/modem-at-command/) and report back: `AT^SYSCFG=13` (that should put it in 3G mode, 14 is 3G)

Comment: @Fabby Thanks for the inputs! I configured `minicom` to talk to my modem over `ttyUSB2` and typing `AT` returns `OK`. However, on trying `AT^SYSCFG=13`, the modem replies : `+CME ERROR: 50`. What to do?

Comment: @Fabby The shown error corresponds to " Requested facility not subscribed ". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fully control your modem, best is to install [minicom](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/modem-at-command/) by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install minicom
```

then look which device your modem is using by:

```
ls /dev/ttyUSB*
```

and configuring minicom by:

```
sudo minicom -s
```

and selecting `serial port setup`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and entering the `ttyUSBx` you found earlier where `x` is your modem.  Then save the set-up and exit.

Now you're ready to communicate directly to your modem...  to do this start minicom by executing:

```
minicom
```

and type `AT`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  If the modem is ready and working, it should respond with `OK`.  If that does not work, go back to configuring minicom and change the BAUD rate until it works. (look up the maximum BAUD rate of your modem in its manual)

The full Huawei AT command set can be found in [this document](http://www.net139.com/UploadFile/menu/HUAWEI%20UMTS%20Datacard%20Modem%20AT%20Command%20Interface%20Specification_V2.3.pdf).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have the exact same modem as you...  So what works for mine is not working for yours.  Therefore, I've given you the manual to yours.  Better then that I cannot do. (and better then you had.)  Now you should be able to switch between 2G and 3G after reading the manual!  ;-)

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: For anyone running these commands in the future, you need to be root. So make sure you run `sudo -i` before configuring and running `minicom`.

Comment: Answer edited.  For the future: you can edit any answer as well!  :-)